# How to prevent two objects in collisions from crossing both

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d, collision

I want to know how to prevent an object in crossing another.  I have a ball and a square which I can move whith my mouse. When my ball is on my square I move it (in top for example) if I go very slowly the ball remains on the square if not it crosses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if both of your 2 object have a fixture defined they will not be able to crossing one another this is an exmple of how a dynamic object who will be affected by physics in the BOX2D world must be created , and also this object can't tunneling through a sensor :

```
public Ball (World world){


        this.world = world;


        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
        bodyDef.position.set(0.0f/RATE, 0.0f/RATE);
        Ballbody = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        radius = (int) (Math.random()*30+15); // you can set a non randum raduis 
        circle.m_radius = radius/RATE;

        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = circle;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
        fixtureDef.density = 2.0f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
        fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;
        Ballbody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        Ballbody.getFixtureList().setUserData("Ballounaton"); // optional 

        Vec2 ballVec = new Vec2((float) (Math.random()*8+2),0.0f);
        Ballbody.setLinearVelocity(ballVec);

    }
```

make sure to define a fixture to your box2d dynamic or static object to avoid tunneling through a sensor like in this exmple :

```
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = circle;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
            fixtureDef.density = 2.0f;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
            fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;
            Ballbody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
```

according to BOX2D official documentation :

> Recall that shapes don’t know about bodies and may be used
>   independently of the physics simulation. Therefore Box2D provides the
>   b2Fixture class to attach shapes to bodies. Fixtures hold the
>   following:
>
> - a single shape
> - broad-phase proxies
> - density, friction, and restitution
> - collision filtering flags
> - back pointer to the parent body
> - user data
> - sensor flag

Comment: It doesnt work when i dont move my square ball stay into it but if i move it (to top ) slowly it stays but rapidly it doesnt stay

Comment: Movements:`if (body.getUserData().getClass() == Square.class) {
              if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
               System.out.println("ok");
                  Vec2 mousePosition = new Vec2(Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY()).mul(0.5f).mul(1/3f);
                
                  PhysicalObject newPhysicalObject = new Square(world,mousePosition.x,mousePosition.y);
                  physicalObjects.set(index, newPhysicalObject);
               
                  world.destroyBody(object.getBody());
                     
              }`

Comment: add the code to you question not here , and format it please !!

Comment: gave a link to the class who manage the body creation that i can see how you are implementing them !!

Comment: I fixed the problem it was on my world step method (60hz)